# How to call a function without calling it directly in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-pointers, buffer-overflow

I am trying to call a function with calling it directly. So, I use function pointers and buffer overflowing. I get what I want however when I debug the program, I get segmentation fault.

Is there a way to get the exact result without getting segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void hello()
 {
    printf("hello()!\n");
 }

 void first()
 {
   void  (*array[1])();
   array[8] = &hello;
   printf("you are first()!\n");
 }

  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  first();
  return 0;
 }
```

The output that I get is;

you are first()!

hello()!

Note: I use Code:Blocks as platform and GDB/CDB as debugger

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is undefined. Anything could happen. And you need to know every byte and bit in the stack-frame for the exact compiler you're using and even for the exact version of the compiler if you want to abuse it like that.

Comment: C does not allow zero size arrays, so `void  (*array[0])();` is bogus in standard C. (GCC might allow it, but you can't access any elements of the array.)  When you write to position 7 of the array, you could be scribbling over anything — and you might get a crash which is fine. It's undefined behaviour. It appears you end up in `hello()` — that's a perfectly acceptable response too. Change the 0 to at least 8 and you might be in with a chance.  (Aside: since you use neither `argc` nor `argv` in `main()`, you should define it as `int main(void)` to avoid warnings about unused variables.)

Comment: Undefined variable `array[0]`!

Comment: Can anyone explain how `first()` function works?

Comment: `void  (*array[1])();
   array[8] = &hello;
   printf("you are first()!\n");
   (*array[8])();` last line array[0-7] cause seg fault. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an array with size of 1 and trying to assign something to its 9th(index of arrays starts from 0) index. `array[8]` was not allocated in here. That's the reason of segmentation fault. To get rid of this, you should assign `hello` to an index that is within the size of `array`. In your case,

```
void first()
{
    void  (*array[1])();
    array[0] = &hello;
    printf("you are first()!\n");
}
```

will solve the problem. Above code will print `hello()!` function. In order to do that, you should call the `hello` function as well.

```
void first()
{
    void  (*array[1])();
    array[0] = &hello;
    printf("you are first()!\n");
    array[0]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Also, I have a follow up question. Lets say there is an another printf function below the printf("hello"); like printf("Do not print this!");. How do I print just hello and not the second printf().

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You can terminate the function before the printf, jump to the end of the function or simply you can use a conditional state. Why would you like to do that? If you clarify your purpose, I can answer it more specifically.

Comment: Actually what I want is, by only changing the first() function and using stack logic to access the hello function. I am not allowed to make any changes in main() or hello(). Actually it is a network security homework. The purpose of the homework is to understand the pointer and stack logic.

Comment: You need to set return address of first printf() function in hello() to return address of hello() so that when first printf() function finished program can go back to first() function. However I don't know is that even possible. The only think I can imagine of if printf() function directly sets parameters into locals which I don't think they do, then you can overflow local variables to set return address of printf(). Even if you do this you need to set in hello() function.